# Turn on/off sound button not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio

I have it in my settings activity that when a user clicks the ToggleButton it's supposed to mute the sound throughout my application but it's not working.The SoundPool onClick button sounds I putted in my Tutorial classes are still playing sound onClick.I already specified my Shared Preferences with the ToggleButton.

Here is my code,

```
    package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class Settings extends Activity {











    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);


        Button Notifications = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Notifications);
        Button Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        Button AccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AccountSettings);
        final ToggleButton AT = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.AudioToggle);



        AT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SharedPreferences appPrefs =
                        getSharedPreferences("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Settings_preferences",
                                MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("atpref", AT.isChecked()); //value to store
                editor.commit();

                if ((AT.isChecked())) {
                    AT.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);

                  } else {
                    AT.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
                      }
                 }

        });







        SharedPreferences appPrefs =
                getSharedPreferences("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Settings_preferences",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean atpref = appPrefs.getBoolean("atpref", true); //default is true
        AT.setChecked(atpref);
        Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {








            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent Intent = new Intent(Settings.this,activity_main.class);
                Intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(Intent);



            }
        });
        Notifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Notifications"));
            }
        });
        AccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.AccountSettings"));
            }
        });









    }
```

Comment: Try to get the value of at.ischecked() just after sharedpreferences debug using that value ,i dont find any problem now .try this

Comment: Your code looks OK try using `Log` or `Toast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled%28boolean%29) of setSoundEffectsEnabled

> Set whether this view should have sound effects enabled for events
>   such as clicking and touching.
>
> You may wish to disable sound effects for a view if you already play
>   sounds, for instance, a dial key that plays dtmf tones.

So this function is supposed to set on off of the sound effect of the view (like click or touch). Not to set on off of the device sound.

For your purpose check [AudioManager](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html&ei=dYROUa22FoHmrAfag4HQDw&usg=AFQjCNHxOBvOlReXWNRSsA79zWyoMe_gbQ&sig2=fKMDwlQlP1poF6UZNzGhYQ&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk)

Comment: Thanks I'd figured it was something like that I'll look up AudioManager for this!

Comment: search to mute unmute device in so.. I bet you will find the solution quickly

Comment: setSoundEffectsEnabled i have set it to false on one of my button but no effect. it still produce sound. tested on Google Nexus 10

Comment: the problem was with performClick() it doesn't respect the `setSoundEffectsEnabled(false)`